# Animate span based on variable selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to animate a span within a div, based on a selection within ul?

I used an unordered list to create my nav.

I have the idea that selecting the li will change a global variable, and that I can use jQuery to animate the span within the div based on what my variable says?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43rt2/

```
<ul id='nav'>
    <li id='a'>First</li>
    <li id='b'>Second</li>
    <li id='c'>Third</li>
</ul>

<div id='container'>
    <div class='page' id='first'>Content From 'a'</div>
    <div class='page' id='second'>Content From 'b'</div>
    <div class='page' id='third'>Content From 'c'</div>
</div>
```

I want the containers of content to slide from left to right based on which 'li' is currently selected. I just dont know what direction i should be looking in.

I dont want you to do this for me, instead hint towards a certain type of syntax for me to Google.

Comment: `I cant post relevant code, I am in a rush.` Then don't post question

Comment: `Is there a way to animate a span within a div, based on a selection within ul?` Sure there is...

Comment: Globals are bad, mmkay.

Comment: @Satpal I updated the post, is it sufficient?

Comment: @RyanKinal Why are Global Variables bad?

Comment: Yep its good enough, Now your question is open